# No Method Error for Current User Variables in ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, erb, nomethoderror

In my rails app I'm using erb to display an image of a blank checkbox if the user has not taken a certain quiz, but a checked box if they have.  My if statement is:

```
<% if current_user.bal_code.nil? || current_user.flex_code.nil?%>
   <a href="app/views/users/show.html.erb"><%= image_tag "Checkbox Blank.png", class: "sf-checkbox", alt: "Blank Checkbox"%>
   <h5><strong>Step 4: <br class="xs-none"></strong>Finish Your Profile</h5></a>
<% else %>
   <%= image_tag "Checkbox Green.png", class: "sf-checkbox", alt: "Checked Checkbox"%>
   <h5><strong>Step 4: <br class="xs-none"></strong>Finish Your Profile</h5>
<% end %>
```

I get a no method error saying `undefined method 'bal_code' for #<User:0x007fd7edc41040>` for this if statement, but a previous if/else statement in which I used `<% if current_user.gender.nil? %>` worked perfectly fine.  I'm not able to figure out why `current_user.gender` works, but `current_user.bal_code` is throwing up an error?

If it helps, this is in my `application.html.erb` code (it's on the footer of each page).  Here are the appropriate database structures from my schema:

```
create_table "bal_quizzes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  ...
  t.string   "bal_code"
end

add_index "bal_quizzes", ["user_id"], name: "index_bal_quizzes_on_user_id"

...

create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  t.string   "gender"
...
end
```

Can anyone help me with why I'm getting this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an has_one method in your user model.

More information about relationships:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association

Edit:

The bal_code attribute is only available in the bal_quiz model. So not on user.

Comment: You're right that the bal_code variable wasn't available except in the bal_quiz model.  I ended up using `current_user.bal_quiz.nil?` as a workaround, but I still don't know how I would do it if it was necessary to check just for the presence of one variable inside the `bal_quiz` model instead of the quiz itself?

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` returns a `User` object representing the current user. When you are doing `current_user.bal_code`, you are invoking the `bal_code` method on that `User` object. Assuming `User` is an `ActiveRecord` model, it responds to `bal_code` if the table called `users` contains the field `bal_code`. It does not, and this is why you're getting that error.

Since you're saying you want to know "if the user has not taken a certain quiz", I assume your view gets that "certain quiz" in an instance variable from the controller, like `@quiz`. If so, since `bal_quizzes` contain the field `baz_code`, your if statement should look like `<% if @quiz.bal_code.nil? ... %>` instead of `<% if current_user.bal_code.nil? ... %>`